# Convert android app to smart TVs

Tags: android, android-tv, smart-tv

We have developed an app as part of digital signage platform, to control multiple screens remotely using a web based dashboard. Currently we are installing the app in mini-pcs and selling it as a product.

Once deployed, this Android player app works as a standalone player with no user interaction what-so-ever, but only on mini-pcs.

What major changes are necessary for converting this app to work for smart TVs with Android TV OS ?

Answer (score 2):

you can try Smaf.tv, the free cross-platform JS SDK and command line tool, with which you can build and package TV apps with one code base for LG WebOS, Samsung Smart TV (Orsay) & Tizen, Android TV and Amazon Fire TV.

Disclaimer: I am part of the Smaf.tv team, but honestly I believe it fits your objective

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an Android app, then it technically should already work with Android TV. There are a few [TV-specific things](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html) you can do:

- Declare a Leanback Launcher intent. Add this to your main activity in the manifest:

  ```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  ```
- Add a banner to your app's application tag:

  ```
  <application
      android:banner="@drawable/banner" >
  ```
- Test it out to make sure any user interaction you have works with a DPAD / remote control.

You can build and run on a device or in an emulator if you want to double-check. There's plenty more in the docs linked above if you want to learn more.